# Why is bzip2 needed in the kernel patch instructions?

Tags: kernel, patch

This was from [here](http://wiki.karen.net.nz/index.php/Network_Diagnostic_Tool_%28NDT%29).

**Extract the patch**

```
tar -xvzf /usr/src/web100-2.5.22-200810130047.tar.gz

bzip2 web100/ web100-2.6.27-2.5.22-200810130047.patch
```

**Test the patch**

```
bzip2 -dc /usr/src/linux/web100/ web100-2.6.27-2.5.22-200810130047.patch.bz2 | patch -p1 --dry-run
```

I looked at the `.patch`, the diff output of many files and the file `.patch.bz2` after the `bzip2` command which is too also the diff output of many files, they seem to be the same. My question is why is bzip2 even needed to turn the `.patch` into a `.patch.bz2`? Is it for the redirection to std output from the `-dc` option for the patch command? Even if it is, why not just not just use the patch command in the form something like this:`patch -p1 < patchfile`? I don't see why the bzip2 is done here.

Also, I think the bzip2 might have an extra space in the command after `web100/`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct, there does appear to be an extra space character in `web100/ web100` that should not be there and will break the command.
2. I agree, there appears to be no obvious reason for using `bzip2` in the example.  Normally one would just do  `patch -p1 < ../my.patch`.

Have you considered getting in contact with the authors of that webpage and letting them know that they can simplify the instructions?

Comment: I've seen quite a few tutorials that do this. For example: (http://ck.wikia.com/wiki/WalkThrough), (http://www.howtoforge.com/kernel_compilation_ubuntu) and (http://www.howtoforge.com/network-diagnostic-tool-ndt-ubuntu-7.10-server-p2) Is there a particular reason why?